# C++: standard way of Qt's QObject threaded signaling

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, event-handling

In Qt, one can use `QObject`'s `moveToThread` method to bind a `QObject` instance to a separate thread, causing all signal/slot based method calls to occur on this thread's event queue.

Is there something in Boost (or even the standard library) that allows emulating this behavior with minimal boilerplate?

Comment: What would it mean for an object to be moved to a thread outside of Qt? The standard library doesn't come with an event queue.

Comment: @sjdowling `QObjects` can only be "moved to" `QThread`s.

Comment: @SimonWarta yes but what that "moving" implies is that the signal/slot mechanism for that object processes events using the event loop of a different thread object. The standard library doesn't have an event loop or a signal/slot mechanism so there isn't really an equivalent here to begin with.

Comment: If this is possible at all it will be with the [boost signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/signals2.html) library.